# I have solved a program in hacker rank but it shows the error "Termination due to timeout". But I got a test case solved correctly

Tags: c

***Problem Statement***

James found a love letter his friend Harry has written for his girlfriend. James is a prankster, so he decides to meddle with the letter. He changes all the words in the letter into palindromes.

To do this, he follows two rules:

He can reduce the value of a letter, e.g. he can change d to c, but he cannot change c to d.
In order to form a palindrome, if he has to repeatedly reduce the value of a letter, he can do it until the letter becomes a. Once a letter has been changed to a, it can no longer be changed.
Each reduction in the value of any letter is counted as a single operation. Find the minimum number of operations required to convert a given string into a palindrome.

***Input Format***

The first line contains an integer T, i.e., the number of test cases. 
The next T lines will contain a string each. The strings do not contain any spaces.

Constraints 
1≤T≤10 
1≤ length of string ≤104 
All characters are lower case English letters.

***Output Format***

A single line containing the number of minimum operations corresponding to each test case.

***Sample Input***

```
4
abc
abcba
abcd
cba
```

***Sample Output***

```
2 0 4 2
```

***Explanation***

For the first test case, abc -> abb -> aba.
For the second test case, abcba is already a palindromic string.
For the third test case, abcd -> abcc -> abcb -> abca = abca -> abba.
For the fourth test case, cba -> bba -> aba.

***Here is my program***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int checkpal(char pal[10000])
{
    char pal1[10000];
    int i,j,len;
    strcpy(pal1,pal);
    len=strlen(pal);
    i = 0;
    j = len-1;
    while (i < j) 
    {
        char temp;
      temp = pal[i];
      pal[i] = pal[j];
      pal[j] = temp;
      i++;
      j--;
   }
    if(strcmp(pal,pal1)==0)
         return 1;
   else
         return 0;
}
int main() {

    char pal[10][10000];
    int T,len,i,j,k,out[10],count;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    for(i=0;i<T;i++)
        out[i]=0;
    for(i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",pal[i]);
        len=strlen(pal[i]);
        count=0;
        for(j=0,k=len-1;j<k;j++,k--)
        {
            while((checkpal(pal[i])==0)&&(pal[i][k]!='a'||pal[i][j]!='a'))
            {       
                    if(pal[i][j]>pal[i][k])
                        pal[i][j]=pal[i][j]-1;
                    else if(pal[i][j]<pal[i][k])
                        pal[i][k]=pal[i][k]-1;
                    count=count+1;
            }
        }
        out[i]=count;
    }
    for(i=0;i<T;i++)
        printf("%d\n",out[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please help me why that error occurred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It failed on timing because your solution is too complicated. You don't need a function to keep checking if the whole string is a palindrome. Start with the end of string indices, until they meet compare the character at one index with the character at the other. Then adjust the indices inwards.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    char pal[105];
    int T, i, j, k, diff, count;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    for(i=0; i<T; i++) {
        scanf("%s",pal);
        count=0;
        for(j=0,k=strlen(pal)-1; j<k; j++,k--) {
            diff = pal[j] - pal[k];
            if (diff > 0)
                count += diff;
            else
                count -= diff;
        }
        printf("%d ", count);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Program input

```
4
abc
abcba
abcd
cba
```

Program output:

```
2 0 4 2
```